# "You have held broken packages" error

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, jhbuild

I try to run -

```
$ jhbuild sysdeps --install
```

but run into the broken packages error.

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is the complete log- http://pastebin.com/ZaV34510

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I am following this guide to build gnome-
https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeLove/BuildGnome

I debugged errors like these in the past by repeatedly removing the older packages until all dependencies were met.

But now I get a much longer list of package problems, which removing manually would be infeasible.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Using 'sudo aptitude' doesn't help also.

Answer (score 0):

First list all the packages which is  having conflict by using the following command,

```
apt-mark showhold
```

After doing so unhold by using the below command,

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package name>
```

Once you are done with the above remove all the packages which is causing the issue and re-install it again. Hope this will help you to fix the issue. Please give it a try.

Comment: No packages were on hold. And as I said, the list of conflicting packages is very long, and most of them require their predecessors (recursively) to be removed and re-installed. It will take too much time and I fear that it may introduce some instability in the system.